# Function applied to each element of a list and returns a list of list in R

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, apply, purrr

For a list in R, I want to apply a function that accepts each element in each list and returns three numbers, which is the input value plus 1, 2, and 3. I want to create a list of list such that for each component of the original list, a list is returned where each component of this list is the output from each element of the original list. For all components of the list, I get a list of list.

Specifically,
For list `lst <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:5, c = 6:8)`,

I want a list as follows:

```
> lst2
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 4 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 5 6

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 6 7


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[3]][[2]]
[1]  8  9 10

[[3]][[3]]
[1]  9 10 11
```

I want to complete the task using map function or related functions in purr(r) package(s) in  tidyverse ecosystem. Using Map or apply family of functions in base r is fine. I just do not want to use for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `lapply` or `purrr::map` you could do:

```r
lst <- list(a = 1:3, b = 4:5, c = 6:8)

lst |>
  unname() |>
  lapply(\(el) lapply(el, \(x) seq(length(el)) + x))
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 2 3 4
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 3 4 5
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 5 6
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] 6 7
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1]  8  9 10
#> 
#> [[3]][[3]]
#> [1]  9 10 11
```

**EDIT** For the approach you tried with `map` in your comment you have to take care that `myFunA` takes two arguments, i.e. you need to pass the length of the outer list to `myFunA`.

```
myFunA <- function(x, n) seq_len(n) + x
myFunB <- function(y) purrr::map(y, myFunA, n = length(y))

purrr::map(unname(lst), myFunB)
```

Comment: could you please explain why no comma is used after `lapply(\(el)` , arent we looping it within the lapply within another lapply

Comment: @jkatam Nop. A comma is not needed.  More verbose we are doing `lapply(lst, fun)` where `fun = function(el) { lapply(el, ... )}`  aka  `lapply(lst, function(el) { lapply(el, ... )})` aka `lapply(lst, function(el) lapply(el, ... )` aka `lapply(lst, \(el) lapply(el, ... )`

Comment: I tried to transfer your solution to map in purr. Here is what I did: `myfunA <- function(x) {x + seq(length(x))}; myfunB <- function(x) {map(x, myfunA)}; map(lst, myfunB)`. However, this did not work since length(x) is 1 in map, which is unlike in lapply, where it is the number of elements in each component of lst. Any idea doing this in map family of functions?

Comment: See my edit. In my code you would simply have to replace `lapply` with `purrr::map`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to solve your problem:

```
Map(\(x) lapply(seq_along(x), `+`, x), unname(lst))
# or lapply(unname(lst), \(x) lapply(seq_along(x), `+`, x))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 4 5 6


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 5 6

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 6 7


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 7 8 9

[[3]][[2]]
[1]  8  9 10

[[3]][[3]]
[1]  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `asplit` + `outer` like below

```
> lapply(lst, \(x) asplit(outer(x, seq_along(x), `+`), 1))
$a
$a[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4

$a[[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

$a[[3]]
[1] 4 5 6


$b
$b[[1]]
[1] 5 6

$b[[2]]
[1] 6 7


$c
$c[[1]]
[1] 7 8 9

$c[[2]]
[1]  8  9 10

$c[[3]]
[1]  9 10 11
```